# Removing a string of characters in a URL through htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to come up with the correct code to do what I need. I've searched through SO and other sites and found answers *close* to what I want, but I just can't quite piece it all together right, and `.htaccess` is a huge weakness of mine.

I'm trying to make it so an entire folder level gets removed from all URLs on a site, otherwise preserving the structure. After that, I need to add ".html" to the end. The addition isn't anything hard, but I'm missing what I need to strip out the folder.

**Starting URL:** `www.domain.com/ANYFOLDER/any-page-name`

(Bonus: `www.domain.com/ANYFOLDER/ANYDEPTH/any-page-name`)

**Ending URL:** `www.domain.com/any-page-name.html`

We have a client who is moving from a static site to CMS-driven, has some great ranks/traffic for his URLs, and is petrified he will lose this (we will not take Permanent Redirects as a solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule for this redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?:[^/]*/)*((?!.+?\.html$)[^/]*)$ /$1.html [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! I'm going to need to take this apart a bit at a time to make sure I understand exactly what's happening. htaccess regex syntax has always left me a little confused (I rarely use it, so my familiarity is weak). I noticed that this is actually impacting linked objects as well. I wasn't anticipating this. `/wp-content/themes/custom/style.css` is turning into `/style.css.html` for example. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Thank you for your help anubhava. I believe I'm running into interference from Wordpress by not handling this as a function. I didn't think this would be a factor; I should have thought better. I have the ".html" part working. I'll ask the question again, but more specifically and in the context of WP. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes WP rewrite rule plays a major role in this.